# Drop Down Menu in Excel - Manager needs to have more options

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have drop down menus set up on excel cells (working on office365), which all staff can access and amend.  I want managers to have an extra option on the list that only they can select. can this be done and how? thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any functionality which would enable you to do so. You can use macros to check user account and modify validation list accordingly.

Comment: I haven't used these before, how can I learn more about your possible work around?

Comment: "how can I learn more about your possible work around?" - this isn't a task for learning macros. You can find great tutorials on-line, once you know the basics you can try to solve this problem, but it likely will take months. Or just hire a professional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:
Add auxiliary column of Account, in my sample is:

**A1   Account**
**A2   Staff**
**A3   Manager**

[image: Auxiliary column of Account]

Go to Formulas- Defined Names- Name Staff range and Name Manager range:

**B1 List**
**B2 A**
**B3 B**
**B4 C**
**B5 D**
**B6 E**
**B7 F**

Named range `B2:B6` is **Staff**

Named range `B2:B7` is **Manager**

[image: Name Staff range]

[image: Name Manager range]

For Drop down list add Account list `D2` first, go to Data- Data Validation, select List and select the Source: `=Account`

Then add another list `E2` by the function: `=INDIRECT(D2)`

[image: list of Account]

[image: List]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Pictures can *enhance* an answer, but please enter the essential information of your answer *as text*.

Comment: This answers only partly the question. Question asks about managing access, so it should restrict users. As far as they can choose their role, everybody can do whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a tentative VBA based solution. Do give it a try. Note that this is only tested on Windows 7 64 Bit Office 2013 64 Bit in a standalone system.

In this example the Drop Down Validation List is created in Cell E3.

In your applicable worksheet, press ALT + F11 to access VBA Editor. Now double click on 'Thisworkbook' in left pane. In the right side code window, select **General** from the first drop down and **Declarations** from the second drop down.

Put the following code into it

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function Get_User_Name Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare  Function Get_User_Name Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
#End If
```

This is an attempt to declare the right function based on OS Bitness. It might throw a compile error or highlight one of the lines in Red based on what OS bitness you have. For the time being ignore this error.

If this does not work, if you have 64 bit Windows, put just the first declare statement and remove rest.  `Private Declare PtrSafe....` and second in case you have 32 bit Windows.

Now just like you selected General - Declarations, now select **Workbook** **Open** event

Following subroutine placeholder code shall show

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

Put the following code in between these two lines

```
Dim lpBuff As String * 65
Dim username As String
Const mgr_usr = "Manager"
Get_User_Name lpBuff, 65
username = UCase(Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1))

If username = UCase(mgr_usr) Then

Range("E3").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Usr1,Usr2,Usr3,Mgr1,Mgr2"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Else
Range("E3").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Usr1,Usr2,Usr3"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End If
```

Did you see a statement `Const mgr_usr = "Manager"`  Replace Manager with the actual username of the manager.

Now every time the workbook is opened, the Workbook Open event shall fire.
First it will attempt to get the Windows username
Then if it's Manager's or everybody else, create custom list drop down menus in cell E3. 
Replace the Validation list with the actual intended list as desired.

**Few assumptions/caveats/limitations to note**

- The code is tested on Windows 7 64 Bit with Office 2013 Standalone PC
- Windows username is not more than 64 characters, if that much length is allowed
- I am not very sure how this will behave on Windows 8,8.1,10 or so
- I am not very sure how this will behave in networked environment, how your username information is stored/accessed, is it Windows domain,LDAP or any other way if relevant. I am not a networking expert.
- I am not very sure if any Administrative Privileges would be needed in order to run the 'Get_User_Name' function in VB/VBA. If so code may not work correctly on all user's systems.
- I am assuming that you have a desktop Office 365. In case of Office 365 Online,  VBA is, I believe not supported.
- As of now I have no means to verify how this will behave if the same workbook is put in shared mode over the network.
- There's no history maintained, as a result user would need to re-select the right option from the drop down every time the file is opened.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use the Get_User_Name function call over simply using Environ("username")?

Comment: Environ("username") is certainly an option, however probably there might be a way to tamper with environment variable 'username' or altogether delete the same, though I have never tried that so far.